# Как при нажатии на кнопку прекратить цикл ? Telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Решил сделать игру в тг-боте. Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопки "Стоп" прекращался цикл while и бот выводил сообщение?
Код:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def sum_bet_func(message):
    global sum_bet1
    sum_bet1 = message.text
    users_id = message.chat.id
    balance1 = (sql.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (users_id,))).fetchone()[2]
    if sum_bet1.isdigit():
        if sum_bet1.isdigit() and int(sum_bet1) <= balance1:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f' Ставка: {sum_bet1}₽\n\nИгра: Crash\nИгра начинается через 10 секунд...')
            x = 1
            while x <= 22:
                if x == 11:
                    global factor
                    factor = random.uniform(1, 5)
                    stop_menu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                    stop = types.InlineKeyboardButton('СТОП-1', callback_data='stop')
                    stop_menu.add(stop)
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f' 1/3 nn〽️ Множитель: {factor}', reply_markup=stop_menu)
                if x == 16:
                    global factor2
                    factor2 = random.uniform(1, 5)
                    stop_menu2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                    stop2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('СТОП-2', callback_data='stop2')
                    stop_menu2.add(stop2)
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f' 2/3 nn〽️ Множитель: {factor2}', reply_markup=stop_menu2)
                if x == 21:
                    stop_menu3 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                    stop3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('СТОП-3', callback_data='stop3')
                    stop_menu3.add(stop3)
                    global factor3
                    factor3 = random.uniform(1, 5)
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f' 3/3 nn〽️ Множитель: {factor3}', reply_markup=stop_menu3)
                if x == 22:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Ты проиграл')
                    break
                time.sleep(1)
                x += 1
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Недостаточно средств на балансе!')
```

Comment: Что делает "Слит бот" в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1516985/1? Каких ботов вы сливаете? :)

Comment: вам не кажется, что у вас в 7 и 8 строках одно и тоже условие проверяется?

Comment: @Brainsluggy, да это я быстро заполнил так xD, но не в этом суть, лучше помогите с вопросом, а то я туповат здесь)

Comment: @ZxNuClear, да, не заметил )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заведите bool переменную flag. В цикле добавьте обработчик событий. При нажатии на кнопку смените значение flag на false и закончите цикл.